# Android: AsycTask won't call onProgressUpdate

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So I made an `AsyncTask` class that runs `doInBackground()` successfully. I have debugged it, and the entire `doInBackground()` method runs correctly:

```
public class MyClass extends AsyncTask<String , String , Boolean> {
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings)
{
    ArrayList<String[]> stories = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    ...*irrelevant code that works*...

    String[][] storiesA = new String[stories.size()][2];

    ...*irrelevant code that works*...

    ArrayList<Integer> displayed = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //calls publishProgress() every 10 seconds with a random String[2] from storiesA
    for (int x = 0 ; x < storiesA.length ; x++)
    {
        if (displayed.size() >= storiesA.length) displayed.clear();
        Random gen = new Random();
        int rand;
        rand = gen.nextInt(storiesA.length);
        while (displayed.contains(rand))
        {
            rand = gen.nextInt(storiesA.length);
        }
        displayed.add(rand);
        publishProgress(storiesA[rand][0] , storiesA[rand][1]);
        long t0 , t1;
        t0=System.currentTimeMillis();
        do
        {
            t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
        } while (t1-t0<10000);
    }

    return true;

}
}
```

As you can see, I made it so the `onProgressUpdate()` parameter should be `String`..., as in the method in my UI:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... stories) {
    TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bulletinBoardTitle);
    TextView body = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bulletinBoardText);

    String titleText = stories[0];
    String bodyText = stories[1];

    title.setText(titleText);
    body.setText(bodyText);
}
```

In case it's relevant, I also defined:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    //will never call this method; it is deprecated in this context
    TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bulletinBoardTitle);
    TextView body = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bulletinBoardText);
    title.setText("Refreshing...");
    body.setText("Murica!");
}
```

So the problem is apparent with all the debuggers I've run. While the entire `doInBackground()` code (executed here:)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.media);

    new MyClass().execute();


}
```

works well and runs fully, when it calls `publishProcess()` the `onProgressUpdate()` method never gets run.

I'm a very novice Android programmer, so please keep that in mind if you have any idea what might be the problem here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you check storiesA.length > 0? You mean publishProcess() is called, but onProgressUpdate() is not called?

Comment: Are you sure that your onProgressUpdate is Overriding the AsyncTask method

Comment: 1) the doInBackground() method highlights (in the debugging) thus assumedly calls publishProcess(), but onProgressUpdate() never starts.

Comment: 2) The method I used, letter for letter, is: protected void onProgressUpdate(String... stories)

Comment: Solved it. I thought that since the onProgressUpdate() method took stuff from doInBackground() that it ought to be in my Activity. On the contrary, I realized (thanks to James Andresakis) that those methods override AsyncTask() methods. So, since I needed to update text boxes, I made the doInBackground() parameter of type Media (my Activity), saved that instance to a local variable "media" at the invocation of doInBackground(), and later called this to update a text box:
    
    TextView title = (TextView) ((Activity)media).findViewById(R.id.bulletinBoardTitle);